# how can JavaFX Application Thread queue updates while busy?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, concurrency

I was studying JavaFX by myself and stepped into a weird behavior from my JavaFX Application (running on **Windows** and **JDK 1.8**).

I was trying to understand JavaFX concurrency model. As far as i know there is a single thread, called Application Thread, that manages both event dispatching and queuing and UI updates.

[image]

I have a handler on the first button ("apri" which is "open" in ENG) that does a

```
Thread.sleep(2000)
```

So as expected the GUI stops working for these 2 seconds.

But, if in the meanwhile I spam click the second button "Conferma Apertura" (which is "confirm opening" in ENG)
, the GUI does nothing for the remaining time.

Once the sleep time ends the handler registered on the second button is executed.

This suggested to me that even if the Application Thread was sleeping, some (maybe "other") queuing thread was running and queued events anyway.

How could you explain this behavior? Is the operating system someway involved in this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. And __NEVER EVER__ sleep the ui thread (not the fx app nor the corresponding single thread in any other ui framework)

Comment: @kleopatra I will provide it ASAP, but the sleep of the UI thread is just done to LEARN the framework. It is obvious i wouldn't use it in any production environment.

Comment: then why do it while learning? No point in experimenting with obvious and absolute wrong approaches ..